# Onsen UI navigator

Tags: javascript, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm looking for learn OnsenUi to replace Jquery in my phonegap project.

I want to make a login page and after switch to a main page.

To do that there is my html code :

```
 <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
         <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,   maximum-scale=1">
 <title>My App</title> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/topcoat-mobile-onsen-blue.css">  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css"/>

 <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>

 <script src="cordova.js"></script>

 <script src="js/app.js"></script>

 </head>

 <body ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">    

 <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myApp.myNavigator">

<ons-page id="connexion.html">
      <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="center">Page 1</div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <ons-row style="margin-top: 50px;">
         <ons-col align="left">
            <div>

              <section style="padding: 8px">
                <p> Identifiant </p>
                <input class="text-input" id="id-input" ng-model="ctrl.id" style="display: block; width: 100%">
              </section>

              <section style="padding: 8px">
                <p> Password </p>
                <input type="password" class="text-input" id="password-input" ng-model="ctrl.password" style="display: block; width: 100%">
              </section>

              <section>
                Resté connecté
                <ons-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.answer" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-init="ctrl.answer='true'">
                </ons-checkbox>
              </section>

              <section style="padding: 8px">
                <ons-button modifier="large" style="display: block; width: 100%" ng-click="ctrl.connexion()">Connexion</ons-button>
              </section>    
            </div>
          </ons-col>
      </ons-row>
      </hr>
      identifiant = {{ctrl.id}}
      </hr>
      password = {{ctrl.password}}
</ons-page>
</ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="app.html">
<ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="center">Page 2</div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <h1>APP</h1>
</ons-page>
</ons-template>
  </body>
  </html>
```

`

And my js :

```
(function(){

var mbdGlobal = new Object();
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen.directives']);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $window){

    this.id = "";
    this.password = "";

    this.connexion = function(){

        mbdGlobal.id = this.id;
        mbdGlobal.password = this.password;
        mbdGlobal.stayConnected = JSON.parse(this.answer);

        alert(JSON.stringify(mbdGlobal));
        //myNavigator.pushPage("app.html", { animation: "slide" });
    };

});
})();
```

But when i start the application i only see the second page.

Plz can you help me because the web site of Onsen don't give real exemple.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the default loading page by adding the attribute **page** inside the navigator. Assuming that your login page name is **login.html**, you should write something like this

```
<ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="login.html"></ons-navigator>
```

Don't put the login in the index.html, hope it helps.

Comment: It should work, in the index.html remove all the content from the body except the onsen navigator

Answer (score 0):

If your project use slide menu template you can easily do it by setting the main page, refer the following code =)

```
<ons-sliding-menu menu-page="menu.html" main-page="login.html" side="left"
    var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="90%" swipeable>
</ons-sliding-menu>
```